# Extract string value from md-card

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I want to extract the string value (Email is verified successfully!) from the `md-card` using Selenium.

```
<md-card ng-if="$ctrl.isMyCompany &amp;&amp; $ctrl.showVerified" class="ng-scope _md">
    <md-card-content class="tradingPartnerVerification-warn ng-binding layout-align-start-center" layout-align="start center">
        <md-icon class="myCompany-verifiedEmailIcon" md-svg-icon="check-circle" role="img" aria-label="check-circle">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false">
                <g id="check-circle">
                    <path d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M11,16.5L18,9.5L16.59,8.09L11,13.67L7.91,10.59L6.5,12L11,16.5Z"></path>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </md-icon>
        Email is verified successfully!
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

I'm using .Net with NUnit framework. My code is below.

```
string ActualEmailVerifiedText = diver.FindElement(By.XPath("//md-card-content[@class='tradingPartnerVerification-warn ng-binding layout-align-start-center']")).Text;
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? It looks right to me. Have you tried adding a wait?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that some class is being added in `md-card-content` in runtime (*assuming you are misspeling **driver** only here*)

Try this:

```
string ActualEmailVerifiedText = driver.FindElement(
      By.XPath("//md-card-content[contains(@class,'tradingPartnerVerification-warn')]")
).getAttribute('textContent');
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the string **Email is verified successfully!** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the text to render within the *HTML* as follows :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
string myElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.XPath("//md-card[@class='ng-scope _md']/md-card-content[@class='tradingPartnerVerification-warn ng-binding layout-align-start-center']"),"Email is verified successfully!"));
Console.WriteLine(myElement.Text);
```